# RabbitMQ on windows 10

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, erlang, windows-10

Good day. I have some problem.
I successfully installed Erlang (9.3) (OTP 21.0), RabbitMQ(3.7.7) all with ADMIN RIGHTS
Set ERLANG_HOME enviroment var.

From the command line called (with ADMIN RIGHTS):

```
SET HOMEDRIVE=C:
rabbitmq-service stop;
rabbitmq-service remove;
rabbitmq-service install;
rabbitmq-service start;
```

But when i use this command to activate plugins
rabbitmq-plugins.bat enable rabbitmq_management

I receive such error:

```
Distribution failed: {{:shutdown, {:failed_to_start_child, :net_kernel, {:EXIT, :nodistribution}}}, {:child, :undefined, :net_sup_dynamic, {:erl_distribution, :start_link, [[:rabbitmqcli57, :shortnames], false]}, :permanent, 1000, :supervisor, [:erl_distribution]}}
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Do you mean Erlang version 19.3? Minimum Erlang version compatible with RabbitMQ 3.7.7 is 19.3.6.4. https://www.rabbitmq.com/which-erlang.html

Comment: I installed Erlang/OTP 21. 
Name "9.3" i took from folder name erl9.3. My mistake.

Comment: Are there any more error messages in the log files?

Comment: No, it's all i get when use
"rabbitmq-plugins.bat enable rabbitmq_management" command in RabbitMQ command Prompt

Comment: Try disabling your firewall completely. Also, what is the output of the `hostname` command, and can you ping it and see `127.0.0.1` returned?